# Any AWS Powershell command fails with message "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-powershell

I am using powershell to create a new EC2 KeyPair using the script below:

```
Import-Module AWSPowerShell
$Region = "EU West"
$ProfileName = "AWS Default"
Initialize-AWSDefaults -ProfileName $ProfileName
$KeyName = "SecurityEssentials"
$KeyPair = New-EC2KeyPair -KeyName $KeyName
```

However it fails on the last line with the following message:

> New-EC2KeyPair : Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed. At
>   C:\Users\John\Documents\Cloud\AWS Setup.ps1:12 char:12
>   + $KeyPair = New-EC2KeyPair -KeyName $KeyName
>   +            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...C2KeyPairCmdlet:NewEC2KeyPairCmdlet)
>   [New-EC2KeyPair], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UriFormatException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.EC2.NewEC2KeyPairCmdlet

Using the debug flag does not provide any new information. I am using Windows 8.1 with the latest AWS SDK and AWS powershell cmdlet

Edit: The problem appears to be with the way the AWSDefaults are set up. It turns out that any command issued after this gives the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error `Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.` can occur when you specify your region incorrectly. In your case, you appear to be specifying "EU West" incorrectly -- it should be `eu-west-1` instead.

For example, if I use "EU West" as my region for `Get-EC2Instances` in a session that is otherwise correctly configured, I will get the same error:

```
PS C:\> get-ec2instance -Region "EU West"
get-ec2instance : Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-ec2instance -Region "EU West"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...2InstanceCmdlet:GetEC2InstanceCmdlet) [Get-EC2Insta
   nce], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UriFormatException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.EC2.GetEC2InstanceCmdlet
```

To list available AWS regions from Powershell, you can use `Get-AWSRegion`. Here's an example where my shell default is `us-east-1`:

```
PS C:\> Get-AWSRegion

Region         Name                      IsShellDefault
------         ----                      --------------
us-east-1      US East (Virginia)                  True
us-west-1      US West (N. California)            False
us-west-2      US West (Oregon)                   False
eu-west-1      EU West (Ireland)                  False
eu-central-1   EU Central (Frankfurt)             False
ap-northeast-1 Asia Pacific (Tokyo)               False
ap-southeast-1 Asia Pacific (Singapore)           False
ap-southeast-2 Asia Pacific (Sydney)              False
sa-east-1      South America (Sao Paulo)          False
```

So here we see that EU West is infact a region, but it is specified as `eu-west-1` instead of `EU West`.  So just refer to EU West as `eu-west-1` and you should be able to set your defaults.

You can explicitly set which region you want to use in Initialize-AWSDefaults:

```
Initialize-AWSDefaults -ProfileName MyProfileName -Region eu-west-1
```

More info on specifying AWS regions can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-installing-specifying-region.html).